# Upload File using ReactJS via BlueImp FileUpload jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, reactjs

This is a newbie to ReactJS.

Could anyone please advise on what to use or how to have a form (with a few input boxes and a file selector) be uploaded in React?

Have been wrecking my nerves trying to use [BlueImp JQuery-file-upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API). The error messages are cryptic and have been unsuccessful getting any useful help from google.

My code is as follows:

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="lastName">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="myPic">
</form>

// Inside handleSubmit() of my component
$('#myForm").fileupload('add', {url: "myurl"});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but you really shouldn't be trying to use a jQuery plugin *inside* a React view.

Comment: @DanAbramov Why not? The main thing is that jQuery component shouldn't do uncontrolled DOM manipulations, that overlap DOM rendered by React. Otherwise it should work ok.

Comment: @FractalizeR You're right, I was too harsh. I only meant that it's often not worth it.

Answer (score 14):

Using a jQuery plugin inside React is reasonable, but because React keeps its own virtual representation of the DOM you should avoid using jQuery selectors.

Use the event target to get a reference to the real DOM node when your form is submitted, and wrap it in a jQuery object to access the plugin:

```
React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(event) {
    $(event.target).fileupload('add', {url: "myurl"});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" />
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="myPic" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: `this.refs.['myForm']` should be `this.refs['myForm']` I believe.

Comment: @HarlanTWood Thanks, you were right. It's even simpler to reference the form via `event.target` and remove the need for a `ref` all together. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 11):

I tried BlueImp but gave up and I'm using a solution modified from [here](http://fitacular.com/blog/react/2014/06/23/react-file-upload-base64/) to do it:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var FileForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data_uri: null}
    },
    handleSubmit: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: this.state.data_uri,
            success: function(data) {
                // do stuff
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                // do stuff
            }.bind(this)
        });
        return false;
    },
    handleFile: function(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = e.target.files[0];

        reader.onload = function(upload) {
            this.setState({
                data_uri: upload.target.result
            }, () => console.log(this.state.data_uri));

        }.bind(this);

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile} />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit />
            </form>

        );
    }
});
```

From there your endpoint should be able to handle it.

Comment: How did you catch the file data to $_FILES  in the server side? I'm attempting to do it your way but the content in my $_FILES is empty.

Comment: For those interested, I worked off this snipped here for a project of mine and then decided to blog about it, I also get into uploading to S3 - http://www.benrlodge.com/blog/post/image-uploading-with-reactjs-nodejs-and-aws-s3 -

Comment: Note that this only works IE10+ since `FileReader` unfortunately does not seem to be present in IE9 :(

Answer (score 10):

To use BlueImp JQuery-file-upload plugin with ReactJS you need to set the `replaceFileInput` option to false. This is because when `replaceFileInput` is true (the default), BlueImp replaces the file input element with a new one each time a new file is selected .. and that is something ReactJS doesn't like.

Found out about this from:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/lXUpL22Q1J8/-ibTaq-OJ6cJ

See the documentation on `replaceFileInput` here:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#replacefileinput

Comment: This is an important point that should be emphasized. However, you don't actually have to disable the `replaceFileInput` feature. Instead, create and append the file input to the DOM node in `componentDidMount`. That way, React will ignore it during renders, so the plugin can replace it without making React angry. This is what we do and it works quite reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my way NO jQuery, using Parse.com

```
var UploadImageForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      myFileName: "",
      myFileHandle: {}
    };
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    console.log("handleChange() fileName = " + event.target.files[0].name);
    console.log("handleChange() file handle = " + event.target.files[0]);
    this.setState( {myFileName: event.target.files[0].name} );
    this.setState( {myFileHandle: event.target.files[0]} );
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("INSIDE: handleSubmit()");
    console.log("fileName = " + this.state.myFileName); 
    console.log("this.state.myFileHandle = " + this.state.myFileHandle);

    if (this.state.myFileHandle) {
      console.log("INSIDE if test myFileHandle.length");
      var file = this.state.myFileHandle;
      var name = this.state.myFileName;
      var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

      var myUser = new Parse.Object("TestObj");
      myUser.set("profilePicFile", parseFile);
      myUser.save()
        .then(function() {
          // The file has been saved to User.
          this.setState( {myFileHandle: null} );
          console.log("FILE SAVED to Object: Parse.com");
        }.bind(this), function(error) {
          // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
          console.log("ERROR: Parse.com " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        });;
    } // end if
  },

  render: function() {
      return  (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} id="profilePhotoFileUpload" />
          <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </form>
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

It would be straightforward to modify to handle multiple files or to use native XHR instead of jQuery.

```
var FileUpload = React.createClass({
  handleFile: function(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',  file, file.name);
      $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('success', data);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.error('error uploading file');
        },
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <input className="btn btn-default btn-file" type="file" onChange={this.handleFile} accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
      );
    }
});
```